# How to set custom timeout in alamofire 5.0.2 verision

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

How to set custom timeout in alamofire 5.0 verision. it was working fine in previous versions but I'm unable to find it in newer version.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
AF.sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
AF.sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 30
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Session.RequestModifier to change the URLRequest

```
AF.request(url) { (urlRequest: inout URLRequest) in
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private lazy var alamoFireManager: SessionManager? = {
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
    let alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    return alamoFireManager

}()
```

Comment: my question was for version 5.0.2. \